# How to enable an USB device from Powershell

Tags: powershell, usb, device

I'm trying to enable and disable a USB device from the list "Sound->Recording"

I've found the "InstanceId" starting with "USB\VID_1E4E&PID..."

How can I disable and enable it?

I've tried to use `Enable-PnpDevice` but it did not work.

```
$sound = "USB\VID_1E4E&PID_7016"

Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $sound
```

I expect to see the device enable or disable from Sound -> Recording

Answer (score 0):

> I've found the "InstanceId" starting with "USB\VID_1E4E&PID..."

The `USB\VID_1E4E&PID` substring you've found is only the (partial) Device ID and not the full Device Instance ID.

Use `Get-PnpDevice` to resolve the device before calling `Enable-PnpDevice`

```
Get-PnpDevice "$sound*" |Enable-PnpDevice
# or 
$Devices = Get-PnpDevice "$sound*"
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceID $Devices.InstanceID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've tried your solution but It did not worked.

Comment: Do you have another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a partial field value, you can use `-like` option of `where` with a value containing `*` wildcards to get the record you want:

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where -property InstanceID -like 'USB\VID_1E4E&PID_7016*' | Enable-PnpDevice
```

Note that `Enable-PnpDevice` requires that PowerShell be running with Administrator privileges, or it will fail with `HRESULT 0x80041001` or similar. (See [Enable-PnpDevice docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/enable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps).)